# Probability of me passing the test

Tags: probability

Consider a mcq based test with 4 options given.
There are total of 50 mcqs and 45 is the required score for the candidate to pass.
what is the probability that if the candidate chooses the option randomly out of the 4 and passes the test.

I solved it using binomial distribution by taking using the formula 50C45 * (.25)^45 * (.75)^5.

And if the question is posed in way the I can also get 45 or more than 45 uphill 50 to pass the test then I calculated the probability of success uphill 50 and summed them up.Is this correct?
Is there any other more efficient way tho solve this?

Comment: The second way is correct. Getting AT LEAST 45 mens you can get 45 or MORE.

Comment: but it will be calculated using binomial formula for 45,46,47,48,49,50 and adding them up right?

Comment: Yes, you will have to take the cases ${50\choose 45}$, $ 50\choose 46$... etc

Comment: actually I was asked this question in a interview and he wanted me to think of something more efficient because this is computationally intensive so that is why I asked this question.Is there any other efficient way to do this?

Comment: @user71207 we are gonna do this because the question is posed in such a way that I can get 45 or 47 or 50 right answers and pass the test.

Comment: @user71207 any other efficient way to go by?

Comment: @VyomYadav yes a *minimum* of $45$ is required to pass, but **you will still pass** if you get $45$ up to $50$ out of $50$. These cases must be considered, so you add them up, increasing the probability

Comment: @user71207 Yeah just figured that out

Comment: @AzeemLodhi not that I'm aware of. I think that's just the nature of binomial probability, you will have to brute force it. I would also be keen to know of a $1$-liner solution to this; perhaps someone will know of a super smart way

Comment: @user71207 yeah I told him the same. I can't think of any other way right now this is the only thing in my head right now.

Comment: You can approximate the binomial distribution by using the normal distribution, however for such an approximation to be justified the numbers generally need to be much larger than those given in this problem.  The average will be $np = 50\cdot \frac{1}{4}=12.5$ and the standard deviation $\sqrt{np(1-p)} = \sqrt{50\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4}}\approx 3$... so by guessing and hoping to pass the test, you would need to be more than 10 standard deviations above the mean... an incredibly unlikely event.

Comment: Now... comparing the exact magnitude of the answer between what the approximation shows (using $Z=10$ out of laziness giving a probability of about $10^{-24}$) and what the direct calculation that the binomial distribution shows (about $10^{-22}$), we shouldn't be surprised that we were off by a few orders of magnitude... both numbers were so very close to zero and the numbers weren't great numbers for the approximation to the normal in the first place.

Comment: With regards to performing the exact calculation more efficiently, you can improve this by simplifying further: noting $\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{n-r}$ and so using $\binom{50}{5},\binom{50}{4},\binom{50}{3}$ etc instead... and using $\binom{n}{r} = \dfrac{n\frac{r}{~}}{r!}$ where $n\frac{r}{~}$ is the notation for falling factorial, so using $\binom{50}{3}=\dfrac{50\cdot49\cdot 48}{3!}$ instead of using $\binom{50}{3}=\dfrac{50!}{47!3!}$ for instance, keeping the numbers involved in calculations far smaller and easier for a computer to handle.

Comment: @JMoravitz I thought the conditions were $np ≥ 5$ and $n(1-p)≥5$, which both seem to suffice in this situation. With a continuity correlation, would the normal approximation be almost perfectly correct?